# Dependent Combo Box WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have 5 `Combo Boxes` that are dynamically dependent on one another.
 `Combo 1` filters the contents of `Combo 2` and `Combo 2` filters `Combo 3` and the sequence goes on. These `Combo Boxes` have their `ItemSource`s as `View Sources` from an `SQL Dataset`. 
Problem is when I select another item in `Combo 1`, it generates a
`System.NullReferenceException` was unhandled error. 
In effect I want when I select it refreshes all the other Combo boxes.

Comment: Can we see some of the relevant code?

Comment: You are probably binding to sets directly. Bind to VM's collections which are filled dynamically whenever master combo changes.